# Late non-copyable member initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm trying to initialize a object's member that cannot be assigned nor copied. I need some other tasks to be performed first and the initialization depends on it, so I have to delay it.

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

class A{
    std::unique_ptr<boost::process::child> child_;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::process::pistream> is;

    A(std::string exec, boost::process::context process_context){
        // Stuff that needs to be done first
        // ...

        child_ = std::make_unique<boost::process::child>(start_child(exec, process_context));
        is = std::make_unique<boost::process::pistream>(child_->get_stdout()); // <- error

    }

    boost::process::child start_child(std::string exec, boost::process::context process_context);
};
```

The error I get from this is:

> error C2280:
>   'std::basic_ios>::basic_ios(const
>   std::basic_ios> &)' : attempting to
>   reference a deleted function

If I understand this correctly, somewhere in that line a copy is happening, which isn't allowed. 
The unique pointers are not required. I just use them to avoid another error (no default initialization) but I would be happy to accept suggestions both with or without them.

Comment: `get_stdout` returns a `pstream&` reference to an object owned by `child_`. You are trying to copy a `pstream`, which is non-copyable. You can store a (raw, non-owning) pointer to it, I suppose - or just drop `is` and use `child_->get_stdout()` as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `boost::optional<>` for lazy initialization like this.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dbf4588b22a02fe)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct pistream { };
struct child    {
    pistream& get_stdout() { return is; }
    pistream is;
};
struct context  { };

class A {
    std::unique_ptr<child> child_;
    boost::optional<pistream&> is;

    A(std::string, context) {
        // Stuff that needs to be done first
        // ...

        child_ = std::make_unique<child>();
        is     = child_->get_stdout();
    }
};
```

Comment: Added a full demo (after noticing which member was binding to what reference...) **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dbf4588b22a02fe)**

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `std::unique_ptr` wants ownership of the `pistream`, so it tries to take a copy, which as you have discovered isn't allowed. If you think about it, this makes sense: you certainly don't want `std::unique_ptr<b::p::pistream>` deleting `_child`'s stream in its destructor.

The easiest solution would be to just use a regular, non-owning pointer instead, say:

```
class A{
    std::unique_ptr<boost::process::child> child_;
    boost::process::pistream* is = nullptr;

    A(std::string exec, boost::process::context process_context){
        // ...
        child_ = std::make_unique<boost::process::child>(start_child(exec, process_context));

        is = &child_->get_stdout();
    }
};
```

Of course, you'd want to check that `is` is not `nullptr` before actually using it, but the same is true for a `unique_ptr`.